# Can only a certain area of a screen be made brighter

Tags: display, display-settings

Sometimes it is convenient for reading the computer screen if only the reading region is brighter then the rest of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I saw some monitors that have that option but it was accessible only from monitor's menu and not from operating system. I never saw this on notebook's screen but only on stand-alone display.

I had this on Samsung [SyncMaster 740N](http://www.samsung.com/sg/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/monitor/lcd-monitor/LS17HALKB/XSS/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail) and it was called MagicZone. Personally I used it maybe twice - it is just too annoying to adjust boxes via OSD menu.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the answer would be **No**.

From a hardware perspective this would not be possible since brightness is controlled for the entire display area. This is by design.

Although there are [software](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=software+to+control+monitor+brightness&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) to control brightness for the whole screen available, I can't find any that will allow you to only select a portion of the screen.

Comment: This answer is true for most monitors out there: the brightness of the display is the brightness of the backlight. However, if you're willing to pay, you can get a display with multiple backlights. I don't know how much software exists that can tune them selectively (the primary purpose of multiple backlights is to have a more uniform brightness).

Answer (score 1):

I've got an LG W2361V monitor, and it's drivers/software provide a "cinema mode" icon in my system tray - I click that, draw a box and voilà the rest of the screen dims (to an adjustable amount) and that bit stays lit until I click outside that area.

It's actually quite a nice trick. But, it's not a *hardware* function, but probably some clever transparent overlay work. Taking a screen shot with <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> results in the outline being visible in the screen shot.

The point is - there's proprietary software out there that will do something like what you ask, so it's possible. Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestions of non-proprietary that can do this, anyone?

Comment: propitiatory software? meaning software that appeases? =P

Comment: @Cladui Thanks for that. We'll chalk that one up as an "opps".