# Is it possible to tweak brightness of a certain spot of the screen?

Tags: graphics-card, lcd

On my LCD screen, I have bright spots from high pressure (like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1108346/bright-spots-on-dell-e6410-screen)). The only reply suggests some dubious mechanical solutions to the problem. However, theoretically, I think it should be possible to compensate brightness of some areas using a software approach, e.g., making graphic cards reduce RGB values by some constants for selected pixels. A similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/179536/can-only-a-certain-area-of-a-screen-be-made-brighter) was asked 13 years ago - but since then a lot of time passed, maybe there are some GitHub patches or software to "hack" graphic cards?
(I have AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics, if that helps or definitively eliminates the possibility of software hack/solution)

Comment: You'd need some kind of DIY alpha overlay, plus something to composite that into the screen's final render. I doubt you're going to find a ready-made solution for that. You can't persuade your GPU to consider different areas of the screen in a profile, they just don't work like that.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks! Your comment is the closest to the answer!=)

Ideally, it would be not only alfa - to account for uneven disturbances in a general case (and to cure not only my case but a broader audience).

If GPU cannot be forced to compute different profiles for different pixels, it is possible to adjust the feed into the GPU?

Comment: Only if you can build an overlay, by hand, then find something that can composite it into your rendered image. …which is really just another way of saying "Give up now." or get an OLED screen, or even a *good* LCD screen which will not suffer from this issue. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try "exercising" pixels, now that pressure has been relieved, to see if they'll work better. Not a great probability of success, but free and easy to test with a third-party tool such as [IsMyLcdOk](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK).
2. Get [tinted cellophane sheets](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/colored-cellophane-sheets) and cut out a shape to darken brighter areas. Use a subtle shade, and build up a second layer slightly smaller to make a gradation rather than an abrupt edge. **N.B.:** Verify that the cellophane can be applied and removed without damaging the LCD.
3. Bite the bullet, and replace the LCD.